# Format console output when using "print" for a dictionary

Tags: python

I am attempting to take a python class and have found that the instructor is leaving it up to google to teach us. I have to read two text files, parse them, and store data in a dictionary to use it for comparisons and print results of two text files. Now that you know why I'm trying to do something, what I want to do specifically is print a list of data so that it appears readable to the human eye. Currently when printing I receive a list like the following:

`{0: ('Arthur', '3', '1'), 1: ('Lancelot', '0', '0'), 2: ('Robin', '0', '2'), 3: ('Arthur', '0', '3'), 4: ('Lancelot', '2', '0'), 5: ('Robin', '1', '2'),` ....

I want it to appear like this in the console as just one key value with the mapped data per line, like this

```
  {0: ('Arthur', '3', '1')
   1: ('Lancelot', '0', '0')
   2: ('Robin', '0', '2')
   3: ('Arthur', '0', '3')
   4: ('Lancelot', '2', '0')
   5: ('Robin', '1', '2')
  ....}
```

I do not know the correct questions to ask to find this in google, apparently. I am sure that it is something simple like a formatting flag. This is actually not part of the assignment but I wanted to learn how to do this because later I will have to format output for other parts of this program. Here is the text file that I read as input:

```
Arthur;3;1
Lancelot;0;0
Robin;0;2
Arthur;0;3
Lancelot;2;0
Robin;1;2
Robin;2;1
Lancelot;1;1
Galahad;0;1
a random person;0;3
Arthur;1;1
Galahad;1;1
Galahad;3;0
```

NOTE: I DO NOT HAVE TO MAKE BULLETPROOF CODE, so I didn't. I do not have to consider bad data or any type of exceptions. I only had to make it process this type of a text file.

Here is my code:

```
# readfile(string)
# Purpose: open a text file and iterate though the file, one line at a time.
# Input: string
# Returns: dictionary
def readResponses(filename):
    mapIndex = 0 # used to append to dictionary rows.
    for line in open(filename): # used to iterate through each txt file line.
        if mapIndex < 1:# assign key and tuple data.
            record = {mapIndex: parseForColon(line)} 
            mapIndex += 1
        elif mapIndex > 0: # append key and tuple data
            record.update({mapIndex: parseForColon(line)})
            mapIndex += 1   
    return record

#def readQuestions():


# parseForColon(string)
# Purpose: Parse string data to assign appropriate data to three variables. Slices an input string one char
# qt-a-time until a delimiter is found. Delimiters are disregarded and a tuple is packed into a single variable.
# Input: String - The next line of text
# Returns: a packed tuple
# Called by readResponses(string)
def parseForColon(line): # This function iterates, releases memory, and is called anew from parent function.
        string1, name, = line, "" # needed to receive text file line and slices of that string.
        length = len (line)
        count = 0
        while count < length: # slice the string one char at a time until a delimiter is found.
                if string1[count] == ';':
                        count += 1 # increment past the delimeter and assign next parameter.
                        question = string1[count]
                        count += 2 # increment past the next delimeter and assign last parameter.
                        answer = string1[count]
                        count += 1 #exceed length and break loop.
                        break
                elif string1[count] != ';': # while delimeter not encountered, append first parameter one char at-a-time.
                        name += string1[count]
                        count += 1
        data = name, question, answer
        return data #return tuple.

#parse answers text file and save data to a dictionary. 
answerMap = readResponses("responses.txt")
print answerMap
```

Any help would be appreciated. I seem to learn more from google or other people than I ever do in class, frustrating.

Comment: The `homework` tag is being removed, please do not use it for new questions.

Comment: How is your desired printout of a dictionary any better or more readable than the default version? As far as I can tell all you did was remove commas after tuples. ETA: Now I see that in your posts' raw text you wanted them on separate lines. Pavel's suggestion of `pprint` is great

Answer (score 3):

It looks a lot like `pprint` formatting:

```
In [14]: x={0: ('Arthur', '3', '1'), 1: ('Lancelot', '0', '0'), 2: ('Robin', '0', '2'), 3: ('Arthur', '0', '3'), 4: ('Lancelot', '2', '0'), 5: ('Robin', '1', '2')}

In [15]: import pprint

In [16]: pprint.pprint(x)
{0: ('Arthur', '3', '1'),
 1: ('Lancelot', '0', '0'),
 2: ('Robin', '0', '2'),
 3: ('Arthur', '0', '3'),
 4: ('Lancelot', '2', '0'),
 5: ('Robin', '1', '2')}
```

Comment: I'll go read about it and try it out. Thank you for the idea. sorry about the formatting. I had to edit it as "code" to make the example appear correctly.

Comment: Thank you Pavel. It prints beautifully. I knew it would be something simple. I'm just reading about it now so I can learn what is happening. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Pavel's correct about the printing. Your parsing seems *way* overcomplicated to me though so I'm going to jump in with my 2 cents:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> s = """Arthur;3;1
... Lancelot;0;0
... Robin;0;2
... Arthur;0;3
... Lancelot;2;0
... Robin;1;2
... Robin;2;1
... Lancelot;1;1
... Galahad;0;1
... a random person;0;3
... Arthur;1;1
... Galahad;1;1
... Galahad;3;0"""
>>> pprint(dict([(n, tuple(l.split(';'))) for n, l in enumerate(s.split('\n'))]))
```

There's your entire program in a single line (obviously you'd have to tailor it depending on your input, I'm assuming that it's a single string).

Basically, what we're going is creating a dict that's keyed with the index of an `enumerate` call (which yields (`index, value`) when iterating over a list. The value of each of the lines is a `tuple`, which is the value of each of the lines split by `;`.

Sure, it may seem a little daunting at first, but once you really understand how to use Python's stdlib, reading expressions like this almost becomes second nature.

Comment: Demian, Python is still very new to me so I'm still thinking in terms of c++ on a basic level. I see what you did with tuple(l.split(';'))... I suppose I could adapt it to read though with several method calls. Initially I am opening a text file and reading line by line as a string. not knowing about all of the functions in the stdlib made me just take it on piece-by-piece to make it work. Thanks for the information.